Pouring concrete stepping stones in a gravel path
I have a crude gravel walkway (1"-1 1/2" gravel) and I want to pour some concrete pads to use as stepping stones to make a finished path. The plan is to make 2'x4' concrete pads and fill in the remaining area in between them with smaller 3/8" gravel. Figure I'd need about a dozen pads spaced 6-8" apart
I was planning on making a 2'x4' frame out of 2x4s and pouring the concrete in that. Regarding the details:

Can I just lay the frame over the existing gravel and pour it or do I need to dig down below the surface a bit? Is some kind of a base needed (fine crushed stone, etc)? The gravel is shallow, probably only 1-2" deep, hard compacted dirt below that.
What kind of concrete would be best for this application and how do I figure out how much I'll need? (dry climate, occasionally freezes, little direct sun)
The path is on a slight downward slope. Would I have to level each frame before pouring, or could I make the pavers follow that slight downward angle? I don't want to make "steps" and the slope is fairly shallow.


Is the gravel newly laid or has it been walked on for a long time(compacted)?  The pads should have a slight downward slope to drain water off.  A slight stamp design on top might help traction.  Nothing fancy, maybe just running a finger across/diamond pattern.

2' x 4' is too big IMO, they will likely crack. Why not buy 2' x 2' pre-made stepping stones?

I agree with Mattman944. Patio blocks are cheap and MUCH less labor than placing concrete. Placing and finishing concrete is a lot of work compared with just raking back some of the gravel and placing patio blocks. You can even buy ones with a stamped pattern or colored ones.

@crip659, the gravel has been there for probably 6 years or so getting walked on. I was planning on brushing the tops of the pads with a broom to give some grip.
The 2x4' is to match the walkway in front. I have a picture, but I don't know how to put them on here (any tips would be helpful).

If you use the edit button, you will find a mountain/sun icon to add pictures.

If you live in a place where temperatures never fall below freezing just pouring concrete outside might work out. If winter temperatures are below freezing, concrete will be cracked all over after the first winter.

Gravel needs to be compacted and roughly leveled.
Concrete needs to be minimum 1,5 inches thick
Concrete expansion groves are required.
Concrete needs to be keep moist 3 days after.
Pawers need paver sand layer (compacted) and leveled
